# How to bypass UWP App Certification in an Azure Devops build pipeline?

Tags: uwp, azure-devops

When I create a UWP app package from Visual Studio, running the app certification is optional.
However, when building the app in an Azure Devops pipeline, I don't know how to bypass the certification.

Here is the task:

```
task: VSBuild@1
displayName: Build solution **/MyApp_UWP.sln
inputs:
    solution: '**/MyApp_UWP.sln'
    vsVersion: 15.0
    msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(BuildPlatform)" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload'
    platform: x86
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload` with `/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=Sideload`.

You won't be able to upload the so created package to the Store but you still can Sideload it.

Comment: I thought about it but haven't tried as nowhere can I find documented  the available values for the build mode. Where do you get the info from?

Comment: I did not find any documentation about this either. Had the same problem like you. After a long and frustrating night debuging this, this was the last option for me that I could come up with and it worked...

Comment: I won't try it as I don't need it anymore but I trust you that it works.

Comment: @François with this option it also generates the needed certificate with the same name of the app into the folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `/p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false` to `msbuildArgs`.